# Change column value in Magento

Tags: magento, expression

I have problem with expression. I have one column that i want to delete inverted commas and change value from -1 to 2 and from 0 to 1.

I Used this formula:`CASE IF [CSV_COL(x)] = -1 THEN [CSV_COL(x)] = 2 IF [CSV_COL(x)] = 0 THEN [CSV_COL(x)] = 1 ELSE [CSV_COL(x)] END; REPLACE ([CSV_COL(3)], '\"','')`

But i got error, can any one help me with that?

Comment: What error did you receive?

Comment: Cannot evaluate expression "'CASE
 IF [CSV_COL(x)] = -1 THEN [CSV_COL(x)] = 2...". Error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\"','')' at line 1"

Comment: any body who can help me out here?

Comment: MySql doesn't need the escaping backslash near your quotation marks to be removed in the `REPLACE` unless Magento needs it